# Chrome Manifest V3 - Weird behavior in older versions after release to Manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've recently released a new version of my extension as V3.
Since the day I released the extension, I see that **older versions** of my extension are gaining more users. This is super weird. I haven't done anything with older versions, and I can clearly see in the Chrome Web Store statistics of weekly users, that there is a rise in the number of users, right when my extension was released with MV3. This can't be a coincidence.

Did anyone else see this? Any idea why this is happening? I want all of my users to be on the latest version of my extension, especially on the MV3 one.

I tried looking around the web for answers, but couldn't fin d anyone with this issue.
I know it sounds funny, because who would complain about having **more** users, but I really want to understand why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: Just a coincidence.

Comment: Hey, I don't think it is just a coincidence, because it started exactly when my MV3 extension was approved by google.

Comment: What I mean is - this is just too much to be just a coincidence. The rise started at the exact time when MV3 was approved. This can't be a coincidence, I'm sure it has a technical explanation, whether it is a bug on Chrome, or a bug in the statistics or just an expected behavior where google promotes extensions that already moved to MV3 or something like that, even with older versions (not sure how it can be done)